# Little changes in the given algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

It's about changing a maze algorithm.

What I mean by that? We got a 2-dimensional array filled with 0 and 1 where 0 stands for "not possible to pass" and 1 for "possible to pass".
An that algorithm finds its way from x to y (also known example: cat to mouse).
And this exactly is what the following algorithm is doing.

As input we got:

```
{1, 0, 0,},
{1, 1, 0},
{0, 1, 1} };
```

And the output:

```
(0,0) // ressembles the coordinates of the 1 in top left corner 
(1,0) // ressembles the 1 under the first 1 I just explained
(1,1) // ...
(2,1)
(2,2)
```

I want change some little things:

1. Change the starting and end position (this algorithm starts in top left and ends in bottom right) - I want mine to start in bottom left and end top right.
2. This algorithm can only move down and right - I want only move up and right.

What changes need to be done, I'm pretty sure but I don't know how to code that:
For 1.) the problem seems to be:

```
public List<Coordinate> solve() {
        return getMazePath(0, 0, new Stack<Coordinate>());
    }
```

Somehow, I need to do 0-1 with the second zero but how if I haven't access to x and y declaration? I really believe 0-1 would make me start at bottom left instead of top left, is that right?

For 2.) changes for the column, also know as y need to be done.
Instead of +1 it requires -1, is that right?

Sorry for that wall of text, I really tried to keep it short but I seem to have failed :P
Anyway I hope someone will read this^^

Algorithm WITHOUT the changes:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;

final class Coordinate {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}

public class Alg {

    private final int[][] maze;

    public Alg(int[][] maze) {
        if (maze == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The input maze cannot be null");
        }
        if (maze.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The size of maze should be greater than 0");
        }

        this.maze = maze;
    }

    public List<Coordinate> solve() {
        return getMazePath(0, 0, new Stack<Coordinate>());
    }

    private List<Coordinate> getMazePath(int row, int col, Stack<Coordinate> stack) {
        assert stack != null;

        stack.add(new Coordinate(row, col));

        if ((row == maze.length - 1) && (col == maze[0].length - 1)) {
            Coordinate[] coordinateArray = stack.toArray(new Coordinate[stack.size()]);
            return Arrays.asList(coordinateArray);
        }

        for (int j = col; j < maze[row].length; j++) {

            if ((j + 1) < maze[row].length && maze[row][j + 1] == 1) {
                return getMazePath(row, j + 1, stack);
            }

            if ((row + 1) < maze.length && maze[row + 1][col] == 1) {
                return getMazePath(row + 1, col, stack);
            }
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] m = {  {1, 0, 0,},
                       {1, 1, 0},
                       {0, 1, 1} };

        Alg maze = new Alg(m);

        for (Coordinate coord :  maze.solve()) {
            System.out.println("("+coord.getX() + "," + coord.getY()+")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicates: 
[1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37480866/522444), 
[2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37482819/522444), 
[3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37480866/522444), 
[4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37485751/522444), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37490334/522444).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the method declaration for `getMazePath`. The current 0, 0 is passed as the `row` and `col` to that argument.   So instead of sending 0, 0 to that method as currently coded, you'll send 2, 0 (for row 2, column 0, the bottom left).

The directional movements are in the `for` loop inside that `getMazePath()` method, the two if statements check if there is a 1 in column `j + 1` (the column to the right) or in row `row + 1` (the row below the current one).  You'd modify those to use minus instead of plus to move to the left, or up, respectively.

Comment: Daniel: you're wasting your time. This poster has had this same question answered over and over, and he keeps ignoring the answer, trying to get someone to write his code for him.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. You are going to get the green check because that was what I was looking for, it works like a charm now. And for you Hovercraft, I really don't know what your problem is. This was now my first and last question on this site, I really don't need that if there are no-life people like you doing that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the heads up.  I didn't know he'd multiposted.  Seemed like a simple question and a simple answer to me, and there were no downvotes on the question when I started typing my answer...